# GaugeControl double click event handler

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have `GaugeControl` having three gauges in its collection. I have written its double click event handler as follows:

```
AddHandler gc.DoubleClick, AddressOf HandleGaugeDoubleClick

Private Sub HandleGaugeDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   'Gauge Information
End Sub
```

where gc is decalred to be of type GaugeControl and three GaugeControls have been added in it. 
[image]

My question is, how I can get the information of which Gauge has been double clicked?

**Note** that these gauges are in one **GaugeControl** and added one by one in its collection. How will I be able to obtain the info of the Gauges that was double clicked.

**EDIT**

First time, this code snippet runs fine, but gives `NullReferenceException` second time when clicked on same Gauge.

```
Dim hi As BasePrimitiveHitInfo = DirectCast(gc, IGaugeContainer).CalcHitInfo(e.Location) ' hi becomes Nothing when double clicked second time on same Gauge
If Not (TypeOf hi.Element Is DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Model.BaseGaugeModel) Then
    Dim model = DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Model.BaseGaugeModel.Find(hi.Element)
    If model IsNot Nothing AndAlso model.Owner IsNot Nothing Then
        gauge = model.Owner
    End If
End If
```

Here variable `hi` becomes null/Nothing second time when double clicked on same Gauge. As `hi` becomes **Nothing** so condition becomes false and remaining code produces `NullReferenceException`.

See this code snippet:

```
If (Not (gauge.Scales Is Nothing) And (gauge.Scales.Count > 0)) Then ' Actual exception here
    For i As Integer = 0 To gauge.Scales.Count - 1
        scaleComponent = gauge.Scales(i)
        cGaugeToBeShown.Scales.Add(scaleComponent)
    Next
End If
```

Where **cGaugeToBeShown** is `Dim cGaugeToBeShown As New CircularGauge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the [GaugeControl.MouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event as follows:

```cs
using DevExpress.XtraGauges.Base;
using DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Primitive;
//...
void gaugeControl1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    BasePrimitiveHitInfo hi = ((IGaugeContainer)gaugeControl1).CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
    if(!(hi.Element is DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Model.BaseGaugeModel)) {
        var model = DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Model.BaseGaugeModel.Find(hi.Element);
        if(model != null && model.Owner != null) {
            IGauge gauge = model.Owner;
            // do something with gauge
        }
    }
}
```

```vb
Imports DevExpress.XtraGauges.Base
Imports DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Primitive
'...
Private Sub gaugeControl1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim hi As BasePrimitiveHitInfo = DirectCast(gaugeControl1, IGaugeContainer).CalcHitInfo(e.Location)
    If Not (TypeOf hi.Element Is DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Model.BaseGaugeModel) Then
        Dim model = DevExpress.XtraGauges.Core.Model.BaseGaugeModel.Find(hi.Element)
        If model IsNot Nothing AndAlso model.Owner IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim gauge As IGauge = model.Owner
            ' do something with gauge
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Related example: [How to provide a custom mouse interaction with the GaugeControl.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E961)

Comment: Thanks for your help! As I pasted above snapshot, how I can get second  CircularGaue?

Comment: @you question sounds a bit strange because all the gauges are available via the GaugeControl.Gauges collection. My solution provides access to the "clicked" gauge.

Comment: Yeah! I got it.I have done a bit amendment in your code. Replaced Dim Gauge as IGauge with Dim gauge As CircularGauge. Though I also need to find the Gauge type but its working now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: it works fine but when I double click second time on same gauge it gives NullRefException. Variable "hi" contains "Nothing". Can you help?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher can't reproduce the NullRef with my code-snippet... Have you modified this one? If so, please update you question accordingly - i will check it a bit later